# capture RTSP stream and forward to RTMP

Tags: nginx, vlc, rtsp, rtmp

I am trying to tunnel RTSP h264 encoded data to nginx RTMP server witth ffmpeg, but its not working

my cmd line:

```
ffmpeg -y -i rtsp://192.168.1.84:6880/test.264 -c:v copy -an -map 0:0 -f mp4 -rtmp_buffer 100 -rtmp_live live rtmp://localhost/live/streamNam
```

VLC is able to decode `rtsp://192.168.1.84:6880/test.264` fine.. Are there any additional options I can forward to ffmpeg for simple tunneling operation? Right now it stalls for a good amount of time doing probing - how to get rid of that too?

Comment: I know it doest work, but what DOES it do? Do you get an error? Does ffmpeg exit? And why do you have -f mp4  in there?

Comment: @szatmary It stalls for quite a long time, probably inspecting the rtsp stream, then it starts processing data - but rtmp output is not understood by VLC. I was hoping I could get help with parameters

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).